# Split string based on delimiter and word using re

Tags: python, regex

I am using Python for natural language processing. I am trying to split my input string using `re`. I want to split using `;,.` as well as word `but`.

```
import re
print (re.split("[;,.]", 'i am; working here but you are. working here, as well'))

['i am', ' working here but you are', ' working here', ' as well']
```

How to do that? When I put in word `but` in regex, it treats every character as splitting criterion. How do I get following output?

```
['i am', ' working here', 'you are', ' working here', ' as well']
```

Comment: you want to create bigrams using regex only?

Comment: no not bigrams. It's coincidence that output looks like bigrams. I just want to split based on delimiters and word "but".

Comment: If you want to split it from but and 'but' no need in your o/p , first you replace with that but with any splitting character and split it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can filter as it : `but | [;,.]`
It will search for char `;` `,` and `.` but also for word `but` !

```
import re
print (re.split("but |[;,.]", 'i am; working here but you are. working here, as well'))
```

hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Even this one works:

```
import re
print (re.split('; |, |\. | but', 'i am; working here but you are. working here, as well'))
```

Output:

```
['i am', 'working here', ' you are', 'working here', 'as well']
```

Comment: I just posted another way of doing it

Comment: while you saying "another way" , what is that difference in both code ? adding `|` instead of grouping doesn't point to another way.